# Pyramid Serving on Local Server

Tags: python, pycharm, pyramid

I'm creating my first real Pyramid Web Application (using Windows). After setting up my application using PyCharm (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/development_tools/pycharm.html), it runs but after running `pserve-script.py development.ini` it says `serving on http://LAPTOP-<my laptop ID>:6543` (where 'my laptop ID' is the 'computer name' that you can find in the 'System' info in Windows)

I was expecting it to say `serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543/` from what I saw from the Pyramid docs and the fact that within my `development.ini` file I have:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```

I'm confused why this is happening and want to fully understand it as I want to make sure it's actually doing what I think it should be doing

Comment: Waitress was updated around version 1.0 to use whatever the OS returns as the name of the socket via `socket.gethostname()` for each socket it is listening on.

Answer (score 2):

That Cookbook recipe is obsolete.  PRs would be accepted for it, but it would probably be best to replace it with links to preferred methods.

The preferred and officially supported way to start a Pyramid project is with one of its [cookiecutters](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/cookiecutters.html).  There is also the supported [manual method](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html).  [Tutorials](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/#tutorials) and examples in the documentation use one or the other.

Pyramid's own internal scaffolds are deprecated, now that we have cookiecutters.

Pyramid does not support PyCharm's internal scaffolds to generate a Pyramid project, but you can ask JetBrains for help, or [bump issue PY-22311](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22311).

Comment: Thanks! Just created it again using the cookie cutter alchemy tutorial. However, still see the `serving on http://LAPTOP-<my laptop ID>:6543` in the terminal once I run `pserve development.ini` but now actually hosted at localhost:6543 like it says in the `development.ini` file. Not sure why it's displaying localhost as the computer name in the terminal but not a huge deal i guess.